# Can't reactive instance in Vue

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, instance

I'm using Vue.js in a laravel framework.

I have declare a `new Vue` succesfully, but when I tried to render data, it runs the error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property.

I tried to fix this but fail, hope someone can help me out.
Here is my code.

hello.blade.php

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')

@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('css/hello/hello.css') }}" 
<div id="helloApp">
  <p>@{{message}}</p>
</div>
@endsection
<script src="{{ asset('js/hello/hello.js') }}"></script>
```

hello.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    new Vue({
        el: '#helloApp',
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'test',
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try defining data as a property? Like :`data: {  message: 'test' }`

Comment: @Eldar It run the same error message :(

Comment: can you try ```v-text=message```

Comment: @KurtFriars I tried, but it still doesn't work. Anyway, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Eldar Yes,  I have defining the data.

Comment: Sorry, but can anyone help?